# Magento2 : List page product shuffle evertime when page refresh

Tags: magento2, product-list

When I go to product list page, products shuffle every time whenever I refresh the page or visit another category.

How to fix this issue? Is this default or I can make changes from admin?

Help me.

Comment: Have you made any changes in product collection in product list page?

Comment: no i have not made any changes.

Comment: If you used any theme in which settings can be there for product list page as in default there is no feature of shuffling.

Comment: no i have not installed any theme just working on custom created theme & inside admin system->configuration there are not any setting to fix this

Comment: Can you paste the product collection code done in List page?

Comment: yes, so may i share that code with you ?

Comment: Only product collection one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66926/discussion-between-sarfaraj-sipai-and-amrit-pal-singh).

Comment: It must be random() function add in code that why it suffle

Comment: no there is not any random() function. This is a core file code so random() is not available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . Go to **Products > Categories** in Admin

2 . **Select The Category** (Product List of Which are you checking)

3 . Go to **'Products in Category'** tab , you will see all products listed there.

**a.** *Default Sorting is 'By Postition' in Magento 2*

**b.** *If you check 'Products in Category', you will see that position of all products are set to 1 in 'Position' Column in Table.*

**c.** *So it Looks like that product suffles everytime you refresh, if you set position of products from there, it will be in order as you want.*

**d.** *See Image For Reference :*

[image]

Comment: Is there any other solution for that ? because this is not possible for every time i have to change that value form 1 to 0 and there should be a more categories and lots of product available in that category.